# Can you run Dind as a service on Tutum so that Drone can use it?

Tags: docker, drone.io

I'm new to Docker and Drone but I'm liking what I've found so far :)

Can you run [Dind](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/dind) as a service on Tutum so that Drone can use it?

Drone CI is designed to run on a Docker host and to spin up whatever containers it needs.

It seems that drone itself can be run in a container but it must have access to the host docker daemon.

As far as I can see on Tutum you don't really have access to the docker daemon from the host.

It's possible to run drone in Dind (Docker in Docker).

But could I just run a container running Dind that I could point my drone container at via DOCKER_HOST, or am I completely misunderstanding the relationship between Drone and Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can and it all seems to work just fine :)

I have my "node" in tutum speak, which has docker running on it, but it's tutum's docker that you can interact with to some extent using their api.

Inside that I have an off the shelf dind container (docker in docker) running as a daemon with its listening port specified in the PORT environment variable (which wrapdocker picks up). That port is exposed (not publicly) using tutum's interface.

Drone is configured from another off the shelf container (for github etc) and it's linked to the dind service so that drone's DOCKER_HOST environment variable can be set to: {linked dind alias}:{port number}

...and it works :)

I feel like this should have been clear from the start but I just don't think that I believed it!